# Case expressions and boolean

Tags: oracle, case

Why does only the first one work?

1. returns 'blue':

   `select case when 'a' = 'a' then 'blue' end from dual;`
2. Error: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

   `select case when true then 'blue' end from dual;`
3. ORA-00904: "TRUE": invalid identifier

   `select case when 'a' = 'a' then true end from dual;`
4. ORA-00905: missing keyword

   `select case when 'b' = 'b' then 'a' = 'a' end from dual;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no a real boolean sql type in Oracle SQL. Neither True or False constants. Boolean is usually represented by single characters 'Y' or 'N' or numbers 0 or 1.

Comment: There is no `true` or `false` SQL keyword, for sure, but `'a' = 'a'` evaluates to a boolean value, without the use of Y/N or 0/1. The Oracle `case` expression is one place in Oracle SQL where Boolean values are used (as conditions, not results), similar to `where` clause conditions.